Matching SMD footprints to transmission line track width
I created a simple transmission line on a PCB (coplanar waveguide) between two SMA connectors.
I obtained the track width based on JLCPCB's Impedance calculator for the 7628 stackup. The track width as calculated by the calculator is 0.3421 mm for 50 Ω impedance of the tracks. The signal that I am going to send between the two SMA connectors is a voltage sine wave in the frequency range 1 MHz up to 1-2 GHz. In the middle of my transmission line, I have an SMD capacitor with 0402 footprint. The thickness of the track there is about 0.5 mm.
In order to make the transition smooth, I used the teardrop tool. Given the frequency range of interest and that the track is thicker at my capacitor, should I expect to see reflections or impedance mismatch? How do you place SMD components on a transmission line when the track is much thinner than the footprint?
P.S. This is a hobby project.

Because your SMD component is 100 times smaller than your shortest wavelength, the impedance discontinuity from the pads is going to be negligible in practice.


Given the frequency range of interest and that the track is thicker at my capacitor, should I expect to see reflections or impedance mismatch?

At 1-2 GHz, this effect is typically considered negligible, and ignored. At 10-25 GHz, it is something to worry about. Of course if you want exceptional signal integrity it won't hurt to do something about it at your lower frequencies.
The increased width of the copper increases the capacitance of the transmission line and lowers the characteristic impedance. The usual solution is to increase the clearance to ground around the component pads. You could use the same transmission line geometry calculator you used to find your track width and spacing for the main line to find a new solution with the wider "trace" width to give the new ground spacing around your component.
If you are using copper-backed coplanar geometry (i.e. coplanar waveguide with a ground plane underneath, or CPCPW) then you can also cut a hole in the ground plane to reduce capacitance. Determining the preferred dimensions for the cut-out is typically done in a 3D simulator like HFSS.

Thank you, this answers my question! The SMA connectors, as well as the SMD capacitor I am using are both rated up to 18GHz. This should be the theoretical maximum my circuit can achieve. I don't plan to use such high frequencies, however, I can always change my mind in the future.  I will take your advice and increase the clearance around the SMD capacitor (using the calculator). Let's see if it adds a few more GHz bandwidth. The precise geometry of my transmission line is copper-backed coplanar with stitching gnd-vias along the length of the line.
